# Git: How to inherit bug fixes from vol. 1 while making unique changes to vol. 2?

Tags: git

I'm working on volume 2 of a music software project that will use most of the same code from volume 1, except for a few small changes that are unique to volume 2.

What I would like to be able to do is to have a copy of the Vol.1 code in a different folder (I use the same folder structure for each project), and adjust it without affecting the original Vol.1 code.
Also, should I find a bug, I'd like to be able to fix it in the Vol.1 code and have the same fix be applied to the Vol.2 code.
So in other words, every change is inherited down, but no changes are inherited up.

I thought submodules could have been the answer for that, but that didn't really work as expected.
Can you recommend me a good way of going about this, so I don't have to copy&paste code and having to fix the same bug multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Have your own branch named vol-2 that you would rebase from vol-1.

Found bugs are fixed in vol-1 branch, with all proper workflow (e.g. github Pull Request), and when you return to vol-2 you rebase your vol-2 from vol-1.

That way no changes from vol-2 will impact vol-1 and you will always have newest changes from vol-1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you simply want two branches and then either regularly reintegrate the first into the other by means of [merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), or by [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) the second onto the first.

```
git branch vol1
git branch vol2 vol1 # vol2 starts with code of vol1
```

History looks like this:

```
A-B-C           < vol1, vol2
```

If you add new commits on vol1 and vol2:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F     < vol1
     \
      G-H-I     < vol2
```

Reintegrate by merging:

```
git checkout vol2
git merge vol1
```

Will include changes of commits D, E, F in branch vol2 by creating a merge commit:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F     < vol1
     \     \
      G-H-I-M   < vol2
```

Alternatively, you can "move" (actually "recreate") the commits of vol2 onto vol1 by rebasing:

```
git rebase vol1 vol2
```

Which will result in the following history graph:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F              < vol1
     \     \
      G-H-I \            # the old (pre-rebase) commits still exist, but are no longer reachable from any branch
             \
              G'-H'-I'   < vol2
```

Comment: Yes I guess that can work. 
I'm just wondering if there is a way to automate this.
Say I continue this and have up to 10 volumes of the same product.
Then when I fix a bug I have to merge 10 times.
Even more actually because I also have lite and pro versions of each volume

Comment: @observantsound it sounds like you have multiple distinct applications all requiring some common core functionality. Why is this common functionality not an external, shared library (a JAR, a .NET DLL, a Node module, …)? This shared library would be maintained in a separate repository with an independent release schedule. Your application would then depend on the latest released version of said library through a package manager of your choice (Gradle, Maven, NuGet, npm, …). Automation tools exist to automatically create PRs/MRs when new library versions are released (dependabot, renovate, …)

Comment: @observantsound but if, for whatever reason, you don't want to do that, then nothing prevents you from using a simple shell loop to merge multiple branches: `for branch in vol1pro vol2 vol2pro vol3 vol3pro; do git checkout "$branch" && git merge vol1 || { echo "Failed to merge $branch"; break; }; done`